# Speech correction API behind Google Pronunciation Practice

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

When ask Google Assistance to pronounce a `word, it triggers an embedded app that allows me to practice the pronunciation of a word or sentence. It shows me which words in a sentence are misspronounced and how to pronounce them correctly. Is the functionality available as a public API?

Update: Added screenshots of the app I was talking about.

[image: launvher]

[image: app]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the embedded app you are referring to

Comment: @Logan I updated the question. The second pic is what I get when I click on "practice".